# How to trigger event when timer count downs to 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

I have a parent component which has timer component inside it. Timer starts at 15 minutes and count downs till 0. When my timer shows time as 0 I want to trigger a submit button event, submit button is inside Quiz Component (Quiz Component is also a child component of Parent Component). I found probably I can use MutationObserver when p tag changes. I am not sure whether it's the correct and only approach or there is better way to achieve this.

**Parent Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/App.css'
import Quiz from './Quiz';
import Timer from './Timer';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ActionTypes } from '../redux/constants/actionTypes';
import { saveQuizAll, getQuizIndex } from '../commonjs/common.js';

const mapStateToProps = state => { return { ...state.quiz, ...state.quizAll } };

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onQuizLoad: payload => dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.QuizLoad, payload }),
  onQuizChange: payload => dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.QuizAnswerAll, payload }),
  onPagerUpdate: payload => dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.PagerUpdate, payload })
});

class QuizContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    quizes: [
      { id: 'data/class1.json', name: 'Class 1' },
      { id: 'data/class2.json', name: 'Class 2' },
      { id: 'data/class3.json', name: 'Class 3' },
      { id: 'data/class4.json', name: 'Class 4' },
    ],
    quizId: 'data/class1.json'
  };

  pager = {
    index: 0,
    size: 1,
    count: 1
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount');
    this.load(this.state.quizId);
  }

  load(quizId, isValReload) {
    console.log('In load');
    let url = quizId || this.props.quizId;
    if (isValReload) {
      let quiz = this.props.quizAll.find(a => url.indexOf(`${a.id}.`) !== -1);
      console.log('In load quiz : ', quiz);
      this.pager.count = quiz.questions.length / this.pager.size;
      this.props.onQuizLoad(quiz);
      this.props.onPagerUpdate(this.pager);
    }
    else {
      fetch(`../${url}`).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
        let quiz = res;
        quiz.questions.forEach(q => {
          q.options.forEach(o => o.selected = false);
        });
        quiz.config = Object.assign(this.props.quiz.config || {}, quiz.config);
        this.pager.count = quiz.questions.length / this.pager.size;
        this.props.onQuizLoad(quiz);
        this.props.onPagerUpdate(this.pager);
      });
    }
  }

  //This event implements restriction to change class without finishing curretnly selectd class
  onClassClick = (e) => {
    let qus = this.props.quiz.questions;
    // console.log(qus);
    let isNotAllAns = qus.some((q, i) => {
      var isNot = false;
      if (q.answerType.id !== 3 && q.answerType.id !== 4) {
        isNot = (q.options.find((o) => o.selected === true)) === undefined;
      }
      else {
        // console.log('q', q);
        isNot = ((q.answers === "" || q.answers.length === 0));
      }
      return isNot;
    });
    if (isNotAllAns) {
      alert('Please complete the quiz.');
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }

  /*
  saveQuizAll(_quizAll, _quiz) {
    let allQuiz = [];
    // , _quizAll, _quiz;
    // if (true) {
    //   _quiz = this.quiz;
    //   _quizAll = this.quizAll;
    // }

    console.log(this, _quiz, _quizAll);
    if (_quiz.questions.length !== 0) {

      if (_quizAll.length !== undefined) {
        console.log('Not Initial Setup Splice', _quiz.id);
        allQuiz = _quizAll;
        const qIndex = this.getQuizIndex(_quiz.id.toString());
        if (qIndex > -1) {
          allQuiz.splice(qIndex, 1, _quiz);
        }
        else {
          allQuiz.splice(_quizAll.length, 0, _quiz);
          // allQuiz.splice(this.props.quizAll.length-1, 0, this.props.quizAll, this.props.quiz);
        }
      }
      else {
        allQuiz[0] = _quiz;
      }
      return allQuiz;
      // if (true) {
      //   this.onQuizChange(allQuiz);
      // }
    }
  }
  */

  onChange = (e) => {
    // console.log(this.props.quizAll, this.props.quizAll.length);
    let allQuiz = [];
    allQuiz = saveQuizAll(this.props.quizAll, this.props.quiz);

    //below code converted into saveQuizAll funstion
    /*
    if (this.props.quizAll.length !== undefined) {
      console.log('Not Initial Setup Splice', this.props.quiz.id);
      allQuiz = this.props.quizAll;
      const qIndex = this.getQuizIndex(this.props.quiz.id.toString());
      if (qIndex > -1) {
        allQuiz.splice(qIndex, 1, this.props.quiz);
      }
      else {
        allQuiz.splice(this.props.quizAll.length, 0, this.props.quiz);
        // allQuiz.splice(this.props.quizAll.length-1, 0, this.props.quizAll, this.props.quiz);
      }
    }
    else {
      allQuiz[0] = this.props.quiz;
    }
    */

    // console.log('allQuiz Out - ', allQuiz);
    this.props.onQuizChange(allQuiz);
    console.log('Check QuizAll - ', this.props.quizAll);
    const aQuiz = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.quizAll));
    this.setState({ quizId: e.target.value });
    if (aQuiz.length !== undefined && getQuizIndex(this.props.quizAll, e.target.value) > -1) {
      // console.log(aQuiz.findIndex(a => e.target.value.indexOf(`${a.id}.`) !== -1));
      this.load(e.target.value, true);
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ quizId: e.target.value });
      this.load(e.target.value, false);
    }
  }

  // getQuizIndex(qID) {
  //   return this.props.quizAll.findIndex(a => (qID.indexOf(`${a.id}.`) !== -1 || qID.indexOf(`${a.id}`) !== -1));
  // }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <header className="p-2">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-6">
              <h3>DADt Application</h3>

            </div>
            <div className="col-6 text-right">
              <label className="mr-1">Select Quiz:</label>
              <select onChange={this.onChange} onClick={this.onClassClick}>
                {this.state.quizes.map(q => <option key={q.id} value={q.id}>{q.name}</option>)}
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
        <Timer duration={900}/>
        <Quiz quiz={this.state.quiz} quizId={this.state.quizId} saveAll={saveQuizAll} mode={this.state.mode} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(QuizContainer);
```

**Here is my **Timer Component****

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Timer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            seconds: 0
        };
    }

    tick() {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            seconds: prevState.seconds + 1
        }));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    render() {
        const { duration } = this.props;
        let timeLeft = duration - this.state.seconds;
        timeLeft = Number(timeLeft);
        let minutes = Math.floor(timeLeft % 3600 / 60);
        let seconds = Math.floor(timeLeft % 3600 % 60);

        let minutesDisplay = minutes > 0 ? minutes + (minutes === 1 ? " : " : " : ") : "";
        let secondsDisplay = seconds > 0 ? seconds + (seconds === 1 ? "" : "") : "";

    return <p className="badge badge-success">Time Left: {minutesDisplay}{secondsDisplay}</p>;
    }
}

export default Timer;
```

**Quiz Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActionTypes } from '../redux/constants/actionTypes';
import Review from './Review';
import Questions from './Questions';
import Result from './Result';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
// import { saveQuizAll } from '../commonjs/common.js';


const mapStateToProps = state => { return { ...state.quiz, ...state.mode, ...state.pager, ...state.quizAll } };

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onSubmit: payload => dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.QuizSubmit, payload }),
    onQuizChange: payload => dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.QuizAnswerAll, payload }),
    onPagerUpdate: payload => dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.PagerUpdate, payload })
});

class Quiz extends Component {
    move = (e) => {
        let id = e.target.id;
        let index = 0;
        if (id === 'first')
            index = 0;
        else if (id === 'prev')
            index = this.props.pager.index - 1;
        else if (id === 'next') {
            index = this.props.pager.index + 1;
          }
        else if (id === 'last')
            index = this.props.pager.count - 1;
        else
            index = parseInt(e.target.id, 10);

        if (index >= 0 && index < this.props.pager.count) {
            let pager = {
                index: index,
                size: 1,
                count: this.props.pager.count
            };
            this.props.onPagerUpdate(pager);
        }
    }

    saveStore(e) {
      let allQuiz = [];
      console.log(this, e);
      allQuiz = this.props.saveAll(e.props.quizAll, e.props.quiz);
      console.log(allQuiz);
      this.props.onQuizChange(allQuiz);
    }

    setMode = (e) => this.props.onSubmit(e.target.id);

    // setMode(e) {
    //   console.log('in mode',e);this.props.onSubmit(e.target.id);
    // }

    renderMode() {
      console.log('Inside here', this.props.mode);
        if (this.props.mode === 'quiz') {
            return (<Questions move={this.move} />)
        } else if (this.props.mode === 'review') {
            return (<Review quiz={this.props.quiz} move={this.move} />)
        } else {
            console.log('Before Results');
            const divSel = document.querySelector('div.col-6.text-right');
            // console.log('divSel', divSel);
            if (divSel) {
              divSel.style.display = "none";
            }
            return (<Result questions={this.props.quizAll || []} />)
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderMode()}
                {(this.props.mode !== 'submit') &&
                    <div>
                        <hr />
                        <button id="quiz" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.setMode}>Quiz</button>
                        <button id="review" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.setMode}>Review</button>
                        <button id="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(e) => {this.setMode(e); this.saveStore(this)}}>Submit Quiz</button >
                    </div >}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Quiz);
```

Comment: The logical approach would be to add a callback event to your timer, maybe called `onTimetDone` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can have two approaches.

### 1. The "react" way

#### In the Parent component:

```
// ...
constructor(props) {
  // ...
  this.state = {
    timeExpired: false
  };
}
    
const onTimeExpired = () => {
  this.setState({timeExpired: true});
}
   
// ...
    
render() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      { // ... }
      <Timer duration={900} onTimeExpired={onTimeExpired}/>
      <Quiz quiz={this.state.quiz} quizId={this.state.quizId} saveAll={saveQuizAll} mode={this.state.mode} triggerSubmit={this.state.timeExpired} />
      </div>
    );
}
```

#### In the Timer component:

```
// ...

componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.seconds === this.props.duration) {
    this.props.onTimeExpired();
  }
}

// ...
```

#### In the Quiz component:

```
// ...

componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.props.triggerSubmit) {
    // Do whatever you do on submit
  }
}

// ...
```

### 2. The "quick and dirty" way:

#### In the Timer component

```
// ...

componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.seconds === this.props.duration) {
    const quizForm = document.getElementById('quizFormId');
    quizForm && quizForm.submit();
  }
}

// ...
```

Comment: Hello Secan , Thanks for your answer.  I am getting following error in function onTimeExpired of parent component, Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: Hi @aditi-lamkhede, currently I am on my mobile and I have no access to a computer; tomorrow I will check and fix the code and I'll inform you as soon as I finish. Apologies for the inconvenience. In the meantime, as a quick fix, you can apply the second approach; that should work.

Comment: Thanks @secan. Just to let you know above code wasn't working and throwing unexpected token error after const so I changed the code to <Timer duration={9} onTimeExpired={this.onTimeExpired}/> and onTimeExpired = () => {
    this.setState({timeExpired: true});
  } which resulted in maximum update depth exceeded error.

Comment: @AditiLamkhede, nope, the way you modified the code is not correct; could you revert it to the version that was throwing the 'unexpected token' error and post the complete error message as well as the complete code of the file, please?

Comment: here is complete code. I have updated original post to include complete code of all 3 components.

Comment: I tried not a react way solution, which works without any issues. However looking for react way of doing it. What are cons of it and will it still be a acceptable solution. Here it is : componentDidUpdate() {
      if (this.state.seconds === this.props.duration) {
        // this.props.onTimeExpired();
        // this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
        const btn = document.getElementById('submit');
        console.log('btn', btn);
        if (btn) {
          console.log('clicked');
          btn.click();
        }

      }
    }

Comment: SO it worked now, I just had to update the timer component's ComponentDidUpdate (called tick method). componentDidUpdate() {
      if (this.state.seconds === this.props.duration) {
        this.props.onTimeExpired();
        this.tick();
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Provide a prop method onTimeFinished in your Timer component. Then in your render function you can add

```
{ !(this.props.duration-this.state.seconds) && this.props.onTimeFinished() }
```

Reference: [React Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Parent Component:

```
// state
state = {
    triggerSubmit: false
}  

// functions
doSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({ triggerSubmit: true });
}
resetSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({ triggerSubmit: false });
}  

// jsx
<Timer duration={900} doSubmit={this.doSubmit} />
<Quiz 
    quiz={this.state.quiz}
    quizId={this.state.quizId}
    saveAll={saveQuizAll}
    mode={this.state.mode}
    resetSubmit={this.resetSubmit}
    triggerSubmit={this.state.triggerSubmit} />
```

Timer Component:

```
// function
doSubmit = (timeLeft) => {
  if (timeLeft === 0) {
    this.props.doSubmit();
  }
}  

// jsx
<p className="badge badge-success"
   onChange={() => {this.doSubmit(timeLeft)}>
   Time Left: {minutesDisplay}{secondsDisplay}
</p>
```

Quiz Component:

```
// state
state = {
    triggerSubmit: this.props.triggerSubmit
}  

// function
triggerSubmit = () => {
    if (this.state.triggerSubmit) {
       your trigger submit code here...
       this.props.resetSubmit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Pradip, Thanks for taking time to answer. I have tried thsi onChange but p tag's onChange won't trigger.

Comment: in timer component,   
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.duration === this.state.seconds) {
        this.props.doSubmit();
    }
}  remove p tag's onChange event.

Comment: Hi Pradip, yes it works that way. I got it working using your and @secan's approach. However I have a new problem now. I am triggering a button click event in Quiz component's  componentDidUpdate. Check out the below code. I am getting Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. I believe it is because timeExpired is getting reset in loop due to ComponentdidUpdate of timer. componentDidUpdate() {       if (this.props.triggerSubmit) {
        if (this.submitBtn) {
          this.submitBtn.click();
          this.props.resetSubmit();
        }
        this.props.resetSubmit();
      }
    }

Comment: can you provide Quiz Component's,,,,, 1. state, 2. submitBtn jsx and possiblly whole submitBtn parent jsx. if you can?

Comment: here is complete code. I have updated original post to include complete code of all 3 components.

Comment: I tried not a react way solution, which works without any issues. However looking for react way of doing it. What are cons of it and will it still be a acceptable solution. Here it is : componentDidUpdate() {
      if (this.state.seconds === this.props.duration) {
        // this.props.onTimeExpired();
        // this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
        const btn = document.getElementById('submit');
        console.log('btn', btn);
        if (btn) {
          console.log('clicked');
          btn.click();
        }

      }
    }